# Cannot get data using mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, aptana3

I have a problem in using mysql_query. I always get the result zero even my query is correct because I tried executing my query directly in the database and I got a result. 
Please see my code below :

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);


mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("login");

$query = sprintf("select * from users where username='$username' and password='$password'");
$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password)
{
    echo "Login Successful! Welcome".$row['username'];
}
else{
    echo "Login Failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please disregard this question. Already got an answer. Thank you for all your help. Really appreciated .:)

Comment: I forgot to add the database name in the query thats why it has a zero result.

Comment: Please, then, delete this no value question.

Answer (score 1):

You use sprintf but you didn't provide variable placeholders, and you use single quote instead of double quote so variables won't be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Help yourself by adding some debugging.

After this...

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Add this...

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Save and re-run the code.

Let us know if you get a mysql_error().

Comment: @sack OK, please do tell us.

Comment: I forgot to add the database name in the query thats why the result is zero. Sorry for this stupid question. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. You must check is query ended successfully.

   if(!$result) {
     print mysql_error();
     die();
   }
2. `mysql` is outdated. Use `PDO`